# Display latest sticky post or display nothing

Tags: sticky-post

On my Blog http://flattrendz.com/, I currently want to display the latest sticky
post.

I used the code of http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/28/get-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress

```
    <?php
/* Get all sticky posts */
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

/* Sort the stickies with the newest ones at the top */
rsort( $sticky );

/* Get the 2 newest stickies (change 2 for a different number) */
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 2 );

/* Query sticky posts */
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) );
?>

<!-- BLOG BAR -->
<div class="blog_bar <?php echo $blog_bar_class; ?>">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="text-center">
            <h2 class="lead">

                <span><?php printf(__('From Our Blog', 'dot')); ?> </span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('%s', 'dot'), get_the_title()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <i class="icon-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </h2>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- // BLOG BAR -->

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php
  }
    else { }

 /* Restore original Post Data */
 wp_reset_query();
?>
```

What I need to do is if there are posts marked as sticky post, then display just the latest sticky post, or else simply display the latest post.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue. I missed the posts_per_page `'posts_per_page' => 1`. Now it works.

Comment: Can you explain why that solved the problem?

Comment: Hi, my assumption is that since the number of entries to return was mentioned in the sticky post array `$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 2 );` and when there were no sticky posts, the number of regular posts displayed was based on the number of results I set to show per page from the settings in the backend. Adding `posts_per_page` fixed this by returning only 1 entry.